# Match at least 1 Char in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how using a JavaScript regexp I can search to see if the string has at least 1 character.  No other restrictions, just simply 1 char somewhere in the string.  I've tried many different things/variations but this is what I currently have:

```
var isOneAlpha = /^.*|[A-z].+[A-z].+$/;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume, based on your attempt, than you mean one _alpha_ character in the string?

Answer (score 1):

If by one char you mean one letter, it should be as easy as

```
/[A-Z]/i.test(your_string);
```

If it can be any non-whitespace character at all, you could just go

```
your_string.trim().length > 0;
```

Comment: Technically speaking, whitespace is also a char. So simply looking for length would do if he's looking for _any_ character. The question requires more definition or your answer will need many variations with qualifications.

Comment: @JAAulde, that's what Matteo Tassinari said.

Comment: I feel so stupid haha, I was completely over complicating it.  Thanks!